# How to convert data int to string while joining tables in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, casting, ssms

```
SELECT * 
FROM Items I
INNER JOIN Stocks S ON CAST(I.ItemCode AS varchar(25)) = S.ItemCode
```

This query throws the below error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'DE15DRM.LPX' to data type int

Where should I use the `CAST` function? Add a `WHERE` clause and use it after?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably need to cast the Int column to VarChar. But why do they have different datatypes if you want to join them? This is a broken data model.

Comment: Can`t we just convert the datatype int to string somehow? @dnoeth

Comment: What are the exact datatypes of both ItemCode columns?

Comment: @learningsql That won't work for you too cause you have a string like `'DE15DRM.LPX'` not like `'123'`

Comment: @sami: casting the numeric column to a string will avoid this error (of course it's still a wrong data model)

Comment: @learningsql Which version you are using?

Comment: How do you think the system is able to convert 'DE15DRM.LPX'  into `INT`?

Answer (score 4):

According to what you provide (Query, Error message), there is a column `INT` and you try to compare it to a `VARCHAR` (string), looking at your code

```
SELECT * 
FROM Items I
INNER JOIN Stocks S ON CAST(I.ItemCode AS varchar(25)) = S.ItemCode
```

`S.ItemCode` is the `INT` column, and `I.ItemCode` column is `VARCHAR` already and you cast it to `VARCHAR` again, because it has the string value `'DE15DRM.LPX'`.

So you can avoid this (for now) by casting the `INT` column to `VARCHAR`

```
SELECT * 
FROM Items I
INNER JOIN Stocks S ON I.ItemCode = CAST(S.ItemCode AS varchar(25))
```

---

Your main issue is not in the `CAST()` function or the query, it's in data modeling (`ItemCode` should be the same datatype in both tables).